# Consulta hijos en firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

saludo estoy necesitando ayuda en realizar esta consulta en firebase con android
por mas que he intentado no doy con algún resultado,quiero obtener esos datos pero no me arroja nada.

[image: base de dato en firebase]

```
DatabaseReference fcmBD=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ET_Bahia");
Query query = fcmBD.child("et_fecha");
query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);


    ////metodo de consurta de firebase
    ValueEventListener  valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            myArray.removeAll(myArray);
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final Fcm_Poo ypoo = snapshot.getValue(Fcm_Poo.class);
                    myArray.add(ypoo);

                }
                fcmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

y el botón de insertar inserta de esta manera

```
Fcm_Poo fcm = new Fcm_Poo();
fcm.setEt_id(codigop);
fcm.setEt_nombre(nombre);
fcm.setEt_nombre_inserto(usuariop);
fcm.setEt_fecha(fecha);
fcm.setEt_valor(lectura);
fcm_bahia.child("ET_Bahia").child(fcm.getEt_fecha()).child(fcm.getEt_nombre()).setValue(fcm);
```

Comment: Prueba poniendo la referencia así: `DatabaseReference fcmBD=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ET_Bahia/09-11-2019/ET-01");`

Comment: Gracias!!. me funciono.

Comment: @A.Cedano coloca el comentario como respuesta al a pregunta asi LosYondris la acepta y queda registrada :)

Comment: excusame, pero aun tengo una duda, con esa referencia siempre estará apuntando a 09-11-2019 , como puedo hacer para agarra todas las fecha insertada

Comment: Listo @GastónSaillén. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Poniendo la referencia así:

```
DatabaseReference fcmBD=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ET_Bahia");
```

Estarías apuntando a toda la información que hay en el nodo `ET_Bahia`.

Si quieres alcanzar la información que hay en la fecha `09-11-2019` tienes que indicarlo en la ruta. Ten en cuenta que en Firebase puedes poner rutas también así: `padre/hijo/nieto`

Poniendo la referencia así, alcanzarás los datos que buscas:

```
DatabaseReference fcmBD=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ET_Bahia/09-11-2019/ET-01");
```

Si quieres una lectura de todos los hijos que hay en `ET_Bahia` lo puedes hacer abriendo un ciclo sobre la referencia y leyendo los elementos uno por uno o guardándolos en un array o lo que necesites.